# Pass data to multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building a view with 2 fragments inside it. Inflating the layout works fine. But I got another problem. Before creating these fragments I need to pass some data to those fragments (FragmentListSchema and FragmentSchemaDetail).I thought of application variables but I guess that's not the proper way. How can I do it ?
Thanks in advance

Inflate :

```
public class FragmentSchemaTotal extends Fragment{


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schema,container);
    return view;
    }



}
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<fragment android:name="kine.gui.FragmentListSchema"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:name="kine.gui.FragmentSchemaDetail"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Fragment` `setArguments` to pass data

```
    FragmentSchemaTotal fragment = new FragmentSchemaTotal();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data","your data");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe not clear, I need to pass data to FragmentListSchema and FragmentSchemaDetail. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to pass data from layout xml?

Comment: I need to pass data from FragmentSchemaTotal to FragmentListSchema and FragmentSchemaDetail they are defined in the XML and are created but I don't know how to pass data to those fragments.

Comment: Why do you want to have the Fragments in xml? you can add it from code as child fragment, so that you can pass the data

Comment: Thanks... Got it working with 2 framelayouts inside a linearlayout and adding a fragment to the framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use loaders inside of the fragments to have them load the data themselves? The usefulness of the Loader kind of depends on what type of data you are dealing with, though. It's tough to suggest the proper way without knowing more.

If Loaders don't fit the bill, you could have the activity find the fragment and set the data on them. Until that happens, the fragment could display a spinner instead of it's view. Once the data is set, the fragment can then display it's views.

The last alternative is to create the fragments in code and pass arguments to them. This isn't quite as flexible though. I would recommend the loader.